# Get exitcode from powershell invoke-command from linux

Tags: windows, powershell, openssh, exit-code, powershell-core

`/usr/bin/pwsh -command Invoke-Command -Hostname PC -UserName boss -FilePath ./check.ps1 -ArgumentList "A","25","10"`

So I am running this command from Ubuntu with bash shell. The invoke-command is connecting with ssh. The last line of check.ps1 is "Exit 2". But exit code alway return 0. Any suggestions to get the correct exit code? I would like to use this command as Nagios check.

Comment: How are you checking the exit code?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.2, any *out-of-runspace* code, notably including *remoting* calls, does *not* relay script / process exit codes.

Therefore, your script's `exit 2` command has no effect on the exit code reported by the `/usr/bin/pwsh` process.

Even *inside* the PowerShell session this exit code isn't available for out-of-runspace calls<sup>[1]</sup>, so - unfortunately - your only option is to make your script *output* the desired exit code, make the PowerShell session capture it, and relay with an `exit` call that is a *direct* part of the PowerShell code passed to the CLI's `-command` parameter.

In the simplest case, if you modify your script to output the desired exit code and assuming that that exit code is the script's *only* output, you can use:

```sh
/usr/bin/pwsh -command 'exit (Invoke-Command -Hostname PC -UserName boss -FilePath ./check.ps1 -ArgumentList A, 25, 10)'
```

---

<sup>[1] For *in-runspace* calls, the exit code set by *scripts that use `exit`* as well as by *external programs* (processes) is reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I believe if your script has an exception, the exit code will be non-zero.  For example, my check.ps1 just has "get-childitem foo" where foo doesn't exist.  This is from cmd, but I believe the effect is the same.

```
pwsh -command Invoke-Command -computername localhost check.ps1 -args A,25,10
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\js\Documents\foo' because it does not exist.

echo %errorlevel%
1
```